# Can I have FlagsAttribute applied to an enum imported from a type library?

Tags: c#, enums, com, idl, typelib

In C# there's such thing as `FlagsAttribute`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options 
{
    None = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
}
```

but it looks like whenever an enum is declared in IDL and gets into a type library and is later imported using tlbimp it ends up as en enum without `FlagsAttribute` even if it contains values with mutually exclusive bit patterns.

Is it possible to somehow declare an enum in IDL so that it gets `FlagsAttribute` applied in the interop assembly?

Comment: Do you really need it? All it really does is improve the `ToString()` overload.

Comment: @DavidG Nope, that's not the only thing it improves. Without `Flags` I have to cast to `int` to use bitwise operations and that decreases type safety and can sometimes cause stupid bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused as to why you have to cast anything?

Comment: @DavidG Suppose there's a method accepting a combination of those flags. Now it has to be declared to accept `int` an the calling code has to craft a bitwise concatenation by casting each value to `int` first.

Comment: No you don't, for example https://dotnetfiddle.net/anhuyA

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?